# Csv import via php after 110 rows doesnt work

Tags: php, csv, insert-into

i am uploading csv file and turn all cells to input form and adding all rows to mysql.

[image: sample of csv]

After form submit ,

it works if i have up to 110 rows and it doeesnt work if i have much more than 110 rows.

I dont know what is missing?

Is there a limitation in php.ini settings?

Or any suggestions for my issue.

Comment: Turn error reporting on. Put this code after the opening PHP tag. Re-run your import and see what messages you get:
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

Comment: Only one "undefined index" error.

Comment: Please provide the complete error message including the line # reported, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is probably a limitation in your php.ini

You have 9 columns.  110 * 9 is almost 1000.  So i assume that your php max_input_vars setting is at the default 1000.  It is a server setting with php.  See http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php